# Electron: How do I communicate with browser window?

Tags: javascript, electron

In Electron, I have the below script is my `main.js`, it's a shortcut that restores the window and focuses it, however I want to focus an input inside the window. How do I achieve that?

main.js

```
app.on('ready', function(){
  createWindow();
  var ret = globalShortcut.register('Command+Control+Alt+G', function() {
    mainWindow.restore();
    mainWindow.focus();
    $('.js-search').focus();
  });
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could send a message from your main process to the renderer process using [webContents](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#webcontents), upon page focus.

The page (renderer process) can listen for that message and then focus the element itself.

**Main process**

```
globalShortcut.register('Command+Control+Alt+G', function() {

    win.restore();
    win.focus();
    win.webContents.send('focus-element', '.js-search');
});
```

**Renderer process (the page)**

```
<script>
    const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');

    ipcRenderer.on('focus-element', (event, selector) => {
        document.querySelector(selector).focus();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome :) No problem.